# Set someone else as cluster admin via kql syntax

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I created a kusto cluster and database as one of my accounts on one Azure subscription, but now I want to grant cluster admin permissions to one of my other accounts that is not part of this subscription.

I have to do this via a kql command, or some other way I can manually pass in which users are becoming admins.

1. Is there such a thing as Cluster Admin permissions?
2. I added my other account as an admin to one of the databases in my cluster using

   .add database DatabaseName admins ('aaduser=username@email.com')

but I cannot seem to do the same on a cluster level. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`Cluster admin` isn't a role you can add principals to.

You're likely looking for the `All databases admin` role: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/access-control/role-based-authorization

You can add principals to that role via the Azure portal, or programmatically as explained here (*note: there's a dropdown for C#, python, and an ARM template*): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/cluster-principal-python

Comment: What is the syntax in kql to add a user to the All Databases Admin role?

Comment: On the cluster I tried to run '.add cluster admins ('aaduser=email')' but I was told I am not authorized to do this action even though I am using the account that created the cluster. I am a Co-Admin of the cluster.

Comment: as previously mentioned - unlike for a database-level role, the options for adding principal to the `all-databases-admin` role (or any cluster-level role) include: 1) using the Azure portal, or 2) programmatically. you do not have the option of running a control command to do so